psycopg2 installation error - UnicodeDecodeError
Issue with Installing psycopg2 on Windows: UnicodeDecodeError and Metadata Generation Fail
I am encountering an error while trying to install psycopg2 on my Windows machine using pip. Here is the error output I am receiving:
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.9.10.tar.gz (385 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [78 lines of output]
  ...
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: invalid continuation byte
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed


Steps I've already tried:

Installing the binary version: I tried using the binary version of psycopg2, but I encounter the same error.
Updating Microsoft Visual Studio tools: I have ensured that my Visual Studio Build Tools are up to date.
Reinstalling PostgreSQL: I reinstalled PostgreSQL to ensure that the pg_config file is correctly set up.
Checking Path enviroment variable for python and postgresql

My pg_config output:
pg_config

BINDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/16/bin
DOCDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/16/doc
HTMLDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/16/doc
INCLUDEDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/16/include
PKGINCLUDEDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/16/include
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/16/include/server
LIBDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/16/lib
PKGLIBDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/16/lib
LOCALEDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/16/share/locale
MANDIR = C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/man
SHAREDIR = C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/16/share
SYSCONFDIR = C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/etc
PGXS = C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
CONFIGURE = --enable-thread-safety --enable-nls --with-ldap --with-ssl=openssl --with-uuid --with-libxml --with-libxslt --with-lz4 --with-zstd --with-icu --with-tcl --with-perl --with-python
CC = не записано
CPPFLAGS = не записано
CFLAGS = не записано
CFLAGS_SL = не записано
LDFLAGS = не записано
LDFLAGS_EX = не записано
LDFLAGS_SL = не записано
LIBS = не записано
VERSION = PostgreSQL 16.4


Additional details:

The error seems related to UnicodeDecodeError in the pg_config file, which may be caused by non-UTF-8 characters in the output (e.g., не записано).
I'm running Python 3.13 and PostgreSQL 16 on a Windows 10 system.

What I need help with:

How can I fix the UnicodeDecodeError or make the installation of psycopg2 work on Windows?
Is there a way to ensure that the pg_config output is correctly interpreted by the psycopg2 installer?


"I tried using the binary version of psycopg2, but I encounter the same error." Python 3.13? psycopg2 is no yet released for Python 3.13 on w32/w64 so you cannot install binary version; most probably pip tried to install from the same sources hence the same error.

Try to change locale in the current terminal to C or en_US.UTF-8.

psycopg2 is not yet compatible with Python 3.13 on Windows. There are no wheels for that available on PyPi as at today. However, wheels exist for Linux and Mac OS distributions. You can use Python 3.12 for this package on Windows.
